# Angular2 route with both required and optional parameters

Tags: angular

I need to create a route with both required and optional parameters that will look like this:

```
/search/chicacgo;place=restaurant;hour=19:00
```

I want to allow search by any of the following routes:

- `/search/chicago`
- `/search/chicago;hours=19:00`
- `/search/chicago/;place=restaurant`

So I've created a route according to documentation:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: 'search/:city/', component: SearchResultsComponent }
])
```

In order to recieve `/search/chicacgo;place=restaurant;hour=19:00` I should call my router like this:

```
this.router.navigate([
    '/search'. {
        city: 'chicago',
        place: 'restaurant',
        hour: '19:00'
    }
]);
```

But I receive an error:
`Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes: 'search;city=chicago;place=restaurant;hour=19:00' ;`

How should I do that properly? Is it possible in Angular2 to have both required and optional params not by `?foo=bar` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
this.router.navigate([
    '/search',
    'chicago',
    {
        place: 'restaurant'
    }
]);
```

Comment: Could you mark your answer as "answered" ? it provides an immediate visual feedback for other users that you found a solution. Thank you